# Custom command line options rails 3 Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a website project that requires ruby 1.8.7 and using am currently rails 3.2. This is a research project and thus maybe a bit "unconventional".

I have a rails server, the manager, that spawns other rails servers which become peers in a P2P network.

I want to pass custom options to my spawned servers to configure them. I thought about doing something like this but it does not seem possible in rails. Does somebody have a suggestion of how to do something similar?

```
rails server --custom_option="CUSTOM_VALUE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will environment variables work?

```
CUSTOM_OPTION=CUSTOM_VALUE rails s
```

This should give you access to it:

```
`$CUSTOM_OPTION`
```